# regular expression to check array of strings

Tags: php, regex

i need to check whether elements of array of strings are made of only a,s,d,r,t alphabets

```
 $array=array('asc','awer','oklm');
```

the above array may take just a,s,d or a,s,t but not anyother alphabet. please tell me what should be the regular expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this trick, joining the array into string, then matching!

```
if(preg_match('/^[asdrt]+$/', join("", $array))){
    print "ok";
}
```

Update: If you want to know how many of those are started with `a`

```
preg_match_all('/(^a|(?<=\n)a)/', join("\n", $array), $m);
print count($m[0]);
```

Comment: and if i need to check how many of strings are starting with 'a' then what should be the regular expression?

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression only works on 1 value. You should loop on each element in your array and check that it's only composed of your letters. The regexp should be something like ^[asdrt]+$